# Find out if image is embedded or not (linked) in Powerpoint

Tags: images, microsoft-powerpoint

How can I find out easily if an image is embedded or not (linked) in PowerPoint?

**I know only the "hard" way:**

**Option 1:**
File / Related Documents / Edit Links to files

Well this will list all links, my pptx have a lot of linked files so it is not very useful since there is no thumbnail or any user interface to link the file path to the actual image in the presentation (MS fail, "thanks" MS developers that don't actually use the app),

**Option 2:** "Brute force"

Rename or delete the directory containing all linked images, and reopen the pptx, if the image disappear it was linked (duh)

Is there any property in the image that says if it is embedded or linked and its actual file path?? This is a fundamental feature. What a heck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing like this in the user interface, but a bit of VBA will show you the link path.

I've got some example code on the PPT FAQ I maintain:

Show me the link and let me edit it
http://www.pptfaq.com/FAQ00433_Show_me_the_link_and_let_me_edit_it.htm

There are also links to a couple of add-ins of mine that make the info easier to access.  The FixLinks add-in demo is free and will give you a complete report of all the links in the presentation.

Comment: Microsoft should give you a job. Microsoft app developers leave a lot to be desired.

Comment: ;-)  They made me a PowerPoint MVP.  That and a paycheck would support my coffee habit.